# Reducing Differential Equations to First Order O.D.Es using Substitution

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Considering the following differential equation:

\begin{align}
\frac{dp}{dt} = p-\frac{1}{a}(1-{e^-}^t)p^2
\end{align}

How would you substitute:

\begin{align}
u=p^m
\end{align}

where m is some integer, to reduce it to the following first order o.de:

\begin{align}
\frac{du}{dt}+u = \frac{1}{a}(1-{e^-}^t)
\end{align}

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

Your ODE is

$\begin{align}
\frac{dp}{dt} = p-\frac{1}{a}(1-{e^-}^t)p^2
\end{align}$

$\implies p^{-2} \frac{dp}{dt} -p^{-1}=-\frac{1}{a}(1-{e^-}^t)$

Let $u=p^{-1}$, then $\frac{du}{dt}= -p^{-2}\frac{dp}{dt}$

Now $\begin{align}
 p^{-2} \frac{dp}{dt} -p^{-1}=-\frac{1}{a}(1-{e^-}^t)
\end{align}$

$\implies -\frac{du}{dt} -u=-\frac{1}{a}(1-{e^-}^t)$

$\implies \frac{du}{dt} + u=\frac{1}{a}(1-{e^-}^t)$

Hence your $m=-1$

Comment: Thank you very much :) I realize the question is very ambiguously phrased and I apologize for that.

Comment: Don't worry, slowly it will be alright. @SmithH

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\frac{dp}{dt} = p-\frac{1}{a}(1-{e^-}^t)p^2
\end{align}
Using the hint given in the wording of the problem :
$$u=p^m $$
$$\frac{du}{dt} =mp^{m-1}\frac{dp}{dt}$$
$$\frac{du}{dt} =mp^{m-1}\left(p-\frac{1}{a}(1-{e^-}^t)p^2\right)$$ 
$$\frac{du}{dt}=mp^m-m\frac{1}{a}(1-{e^-}^t)p^{m+1}$$
$p=u^{1/m}$
$$\frac{du}{dt} =mu-m\frac{1}{a}(1-{e^-}^t)u^{(m+1)/m}$$
One can see that the equation becomes linear if $\frac{m+1}{m}=0$ which makes vanish the term $u^{(m+1)/m}=u^0=1$. Thus :
$$m=-1$$
$$\frac{du}{dt} =-u+\frac{1}{a}(1-{e^-}^t)$$